# Non-interactive access to google cloud storage

Tags: python, curl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage

I would like to use only http calls (e.g., with curl) to make authenticated calls to the google cloud storage API.

Using the google dev console, I have enabled the API and downloaded three created sets of credential information. These information JSON files have the following fields:

- ['token_uri', 'client_secret', 'client_id', 'auth_uri', 'project_id', 'auth_provider_x509_cert_url', 'redirect_uris'] within 'installed' field
- ['token_uri', 'client_email', 'client_id', 'client_x509_cert_url', 'auth_uri', 'project_id', 'type', 'auth_provider_x509_cert_url', 'private_key', 'private_key_id']
- ['project_id', 'token_uri', 'client_id', 'auth_provider_x509_cert_url', 'auth_uri'] within 'installed' field

What sequence of calls do I need to make? It can be assumed that the username/password are available for a user with access to the datastore .

(I believe this must be documented here on SO or elsewhere, but I am having no luck finding anything.)

Comment: For different scenarios the API calls will be different. visit this article for more information: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: OK, so which of these allows non-interactive access, and how to I obtain the various identifiers I need?

Comment: It sounds like you have already set up your credentials, and you're asking where to find documentation on how to make GCS API calls. If so, please see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/?csw=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I followed my intuition, and have wrapped the resulting code in my project [GCSFS](https://github.com/martindurant/gcsfs), specifically [here](https://github.com/martindurant/gcsfs/blob/master/gcsfs/core.py#L195) which can take either the device code route (requires the user to interact with the browser), accepts a refresh token by any means, or accepts a google credential file of the sort produced by logging in with gcloud.